# python dictionary of lambdas

Tags: python, lambda

I've made a python dictionary of lambdas:

```
d['a'] = lambda x: x.count('a')
d['b'] = lambda x: x.count('b')
d['c'] = lambda x: x.count('c')
```

For each key `('a', 'b', 'c')` of the dictionary a lambda function receive a parameter and count how many times appears that specific letter.
This works wonderfully.
The problem is when I try to make it with dictionary comprehension...

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
d = {k: lambda x: x.count(k) for k in lst}
```

... or even with a simple for-loop:

```
for i in lst:
    d[i] = lambda x: x.count(i)
```

The code runs, but when I try to call to a specific lambda, like:

```
print(d['a']('apple'))
```

it appears that all the lambdas count how many times the `'c'` letter appears(!) and not the other letters.
Somebody can explain me why?
How can we make it in a for-loop?

Comment: hm, which python version?

Comment: Reproduced using Python 2.7.3

Comment: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: ah, was able to reproduce, my fault

Comment: Replacing `lambda x: x.count(i)` with `lambda x, i=i: x.count(i)` will do the trick.